# How to get a user public information by Instagram User ID?

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api, instagramapi-mgp25

I have an Instagram User ID and I want to get:

- user profile picture
- username
- full name

on Instagram.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't with the new Graph API.